# fgetc() reads 0c symbol and array elements are nullified? why is that?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have noticed interesting thing but I am not sure if it is supposed to happen this way.

I got some code that uses fgetc(); to read symbols from file and store them into an int say l;

```
  l=fgetc(file);
```

file is opened in read binary mode ("rb"); using

```
  file=fopen("filename", "rb");
```

then using string stream each symbol is converted into hex format and sent into a string and then stored in a char array;

```
  std::stringstream sl;


  sl << std::hex << l; sl >> sll; 

  char as[i]=sll[i];
```

The problem is that when fgetc(); reads a symbol that in an ascii table is represented as **OC** in hex format or **FF** as char my final char array gets filled with 0's.

In short if char[] element contains 0c the rest of elements are 0's;

I have no idea why this happens. When I edited my file using hex editor and replaced 0c with something else. That file was read properly and all symbols got stored in an array as they were written in the file.

If you could tell how to circumvent such behaviors, I would appreciate that.

Ok. Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "u.c"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    unsigned long F, K;
    std::string k;
    char hhh[300];
    char hh1[300];
    char kk[64];
    int lk;

    memset(kk, 0, 64);

    FILE *diy; 
    FILE *ydi;

    std::cin >> k;
    std::cin >> hhh;
    std::cin >> hh1;
    lk = k.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < lk; i++) {
        kk[i] = k[i];
    }

    ;
    bof(kk, lk);
    diy = fopen(hhh,"rb");
    ydi = fopen(hh1,"wb");

    int mm = 0;
    int l;
    int r;
    char ll[9];
    char rr[9];

    memset(ll, 0, 9);
    memset(rr, 0, 9);

    std::string sll; 
    std::string slr; 
    char sL[3];
    char sR[3];
    int i = 0;

    while (!feof(diy)) {
        l = fgetc(diy);
        r = fgetc(diy);

        std::stringstream sl;
        std::stringstream sr;

        sl << std::hex << l;
        sl >> sll;
        sL[0] = sll[0];
        sL[1] = sll[1]; 
        sr << std::hex << r;
        sr >> slr;
        sR[0] = slr[0];
        sR[1] = slr[1]; 

        if (i == 0) {
            ll[0] = sL[0];
            ll[1] = sL[1];
            ll[2] = sR[0];
            ll[3] = sR[1];
            sL[0] = '\0';
            sR[0] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
        }

        ;

        if (i==1) { 
            ll[4] = sL[0];
            ll[5] = sL[1];
            ll[6] = sR[0];
            ll[7] = sR[1];
            sL[0] = '\0';
            sR[0] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
        }

        ;

        if (i == 2) {
            rr[0] = sL[0];
            rr[1] = sL[1];
            rr[2] = sR[0];
            rr[3] = sR[1];
            sL[0] = '\0';
            sR[0] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
        }

        ;

        if(i==3){
            rr[4] = sL[0];
            rr[5] = sL[1];
            rr[6] = sR[0];
            rr[7] = sR[1];
            sL[0] = '\0';
            sR[0] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
            sL[1] = '\0';
        }

        ;

        sL[0] = '\0';
        sR[0] = '\0';
        sL[1] = '\0';
        sL[1] = '\0';

        if (i == 3) {
            printf(" %s %s \n ", ll, rr); //indicated that my rr array had problems with that 0x0c;
            sscanf(ll, "%08lX", &F);
            sscanf(rr,"%08lX",&K); 
            printf(" before %08lx %08lx \n ", F, K);
            omg( &F, &K);
            printf(" after %20lx %20lx \n ", F, K);
            memset(ll, 0, 9);
            memset(rr, 0, 9);

            char RR[9];

            sprintf(RR, "%08lx", F); 

            char LL[9];

            sprintf(LL, "%08lx", K);
            printf(" %s %s ", LL, RR);

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                char ls[3];

                ls[0] = LL[j*2];
                ls[1] = LL[2*j+1];

                int kj; 

                std::stringstream op;
                op << ls;
                op >> std::hex >> kj;
                fputc(kj, ydi);
            }

            ;

            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                char lr[3];

                lr[0] = RR[j*2];
                lr[1] = RR[2*j+1];

                int kjm; 

                std::stringstream ip;
                ip << lr;
                ip >> std::hex >> kjm;
                fputc(kjm,ydi);        
            }

            ;

            memset(LL, 0 ,9);
            memset(RR, 0, 9);
        }

        ;
        i++;
        std::cout << "\n";

        if (i == 4) {
            i = 0;
        }

        ;
    }

    ;

    fclose(diy);
    fclose(ydi);
}

;
```

Since you asked, now you have it.

1. this code will not compile because you do not have necessary libraries.
2. simplified code is at the beginning of this post.
3. those libraries that you do not posses have nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @user3386109 0x0C is form feed, which is not a common newline character. Also note that the file is opened in binary mode, rather than text mode, so conversions like these are unlikely.

Comment: @Rhymoid Yup, you're right. Can we still agree that the OP should post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @user3386109 Oh, definitely. The posted code raises more questions than it answers right now.

Comment: Thats is basically it. file in hex looks like this 78 e9 d4 d2 0c fe ff 15.

78 e9 d4 d2 is stored as is. 0c fe ff 15. looks like 00 00 00 0c.

8 hex symbols are saved in char[9];

Binary mode most likely has nothing to do with 0c problem. Problems start when 0c is saved inside of char array.

Comment: Please add the C++ code of your program to your question as described in user3386109's link. It is not likely that the standard library is doing something weird, and lines like `char as[i]=sll[i];` look incredibly suspicious.

Comment: Will do that in about 5 hours. Time to do some more important things. but thanks for helps. And what is suspicious about iterations? for loop and element assignment.

Comment: I'll look at this in an hour or so, but this is not actually an MCVE. "those libraries that you do not posses have nothing to do with this issue." Then your example is not  just unverifiable, but also not minimal. That requirement is not just there to help us help you; in the process of minimising your example, you might identify the problem by youself. "And what is suspicious about iterations?" Your question only contained the iteration body at that time. How were we supposed to know what it meant?

Comment: You have the same typo repeated many times, assigning to sL[1]=0 twice instead of sL[1] and sR[1]. Your variable names are terrible making the code hard to read. I expect that if you printf "sll" where you assign to it you will find that 0x0c is converted properly, but something is going wrong in the rest of the code. Step thru with a debugger, or add more printfs to trace what happens with that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The core problem

You assume that

```
std::stringstream the_stream;
std::string the_string;

the_stream << std::hex << 0x0C;
the_stream >> the_string;
```

results in `the_string` containing `"0c"`. However, it will contain `"c"`.

This means that later on, you end up converting the input `"\x0c\xfe"` to `'c', '\0', 'f', 'e'`. If you use this at any point in a C-style string, of course it ends the string after `c`.

---

It was quite hard to debug this program. In the future, please write readable and understandable code. What follows is a non-exhaustive list of the problems I found.

## Design problems

- [`while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).
- Use variable scoping. If you pull the declaration of `sL` and `sR` into the loop, you don't have to reset them. Less code, less potential errors.
- You're using a lot of code for something as simple as converting a presumably 8-bit `char` to its hexadecimal representation. In fact, the only reason you ever use `std::stringstream` in your code is to do exactly that. Why don't you isolate this functionality to a function?

## Irrelevant problems

- Because of the poor code formatting, you probably didn't notice the copy-paste errors in the use of `sL` and `sR`:

  ```
  sL[0] = '\0';
  sR[0] = '\0';
  sL[1] = '\0';
  sL[1] = '\0';
  ```

  Obviously, that last line should read `sR[1] = '\0';`

## Style problems

There are many, *many* things wrong with your code, but one thing that easily stops people from helping is formatting. The space formatting in particular made your code very hard to read, so I took the liberty to edit the "full" code in your question to have (almost) consistent formatting. A few basic problems become evident:

- Use meaningful names for variables and functions. I have no idea what you're trying to do here, which doesn't help in finding the real problem in the code.
- Mixing `<iostream>` and `<stdio.h>` doesn't help the readability of your code. Choose one or the other. In fact, [only ever use `<iostream>` in C++](/a/2872576/824425).
- Besides that, use the appropriate header names for C++ (`<cstring>` and `<cwchar>` instead of `<string.h>` and `<wchar.h>`).
- Don't write a semicolon after a compound statement. Instead of

  ```
  int main(void) {
      if (condition) {
          one_statement();
          another_statement();
      };
  };
  ```

  you should write

  ```
  int main(void) {
      if (condition) {
          one_statement();
          another_statement();
      }
  }
  ```

  The `;` is part of a *separate statement*. It also prevents you from using `else` constructs.
- Use initialisers where appropriate. So don't write

  ```
  char ll[9];
  char rr[9];

  memset(ll, 0, 9);
  memset(rr, 0, 9);
  ```

  while

  ```
  char ll[9] = { 0 };
  char rr[9] = { 0 };
  ```

  is more readable.

Comment: upvoted for the fact that you put time into debugging this dreck :)

Comment: Thank you for your full and answer. I am aware about your noticed problems, I believe other people will find it useful too. And this is fine with me, so I am not going to change my obfuscation which is adding irrelevant  stuff to the code. I would have added something very simple to read and debug but I did not have time to prepare something else. But I am a bit curious how much time did It take to debug this for a profesional?

Comment: I think I spent about 30 to 60 minutes on it. That includes time spent on writing the answer, but I only figured out the problem once I cleaned up the program and fixed the various problems I listed here.

Answer (score 0):

This 0c problem can be solved by :

changing char[] array where the value is stored to unsigned char[];

when the input is read with string stream this line is very helpfull

```
<< std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) <<std::hex ;
```

When 0c is converted to c setw(); sets the width of a stream and setfill() pads it with 0's.